React Native (Expo AV) iOS: Error Code -1002 "NSURLErrorDomain" when trying to play local video from the gallery
Bonjour,
Je développe une application React Native en utilisant Expo pour gérer des vidéos locales, et je rencontre un problème sur iOS. J'essaie de lire une vidéo depuis la galerie de l'utilisateur à l'aide du module expo-av. Tout fonctionne bien sur Android, mais sur iOS, j'obtiens l'erreur suivante lorsque j'essaie de lire une vidéo sélectionnée :
Erreur de lecture de la vidéo: The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1002 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain".

Le format de l'URI de la vidéo sur iOS :
"ph://459071C9-B963-4E65-909E-75C90D79E80A/L0/001"
Le format de l'URI sur Android (qui fonctionne bien) :
"file://..."
Question :
Pourquoi est-ce que j'obtiens cette erreur uniquement sur iOS, et comment puis-je résoudre ce problème ? Y a-t-il une manière spécifique de lire les vidéos locales depuis la galerie sur iOS (en particulier celles avec des URI au format ph://...) ?
Merci pour toute aide ou suggestion !
